# Zephir giving error on windows: Installation is not implemented for windows yet

Tags: php, windows, visual-studio-2010, package, zephir

When i build extension with *Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010)* it gives error:

> Cannot load Xdebug - it was built with configuration
>
> API220100525,TS,VC9, whereas running engine is API220100525,NTS,VC9
>
> startPreparing for PHP compilation...
>
> Preparing configuration file...
>
> Compiling...
>
> Installation is not implemented for windows yet! Aborting!

Link to extension+log-files zip: http://modsolutionz.com/utils.zip

Link to error image: http://modsolutionz.com/error1.png

Comment: I would say that `Installation is not implemented for windows yet! Aborting!` is pretty self-explanatory! What do you expect us to do about it?

Comment: sir can you put your sight on my question again! i given the link of log+extension file which has all details about error...

Comment: Well as the developers of Zephir say that it won't install on Windows, you'll have to write your own installer somehow.... or switch to developing on Linux, or use a Linux virtual machine

Comment: i want dll file can i have it on linux please tell me about this thread

Comment: Well for a start, Zephir isn't an extension, it's an actual executable; so it wouldn't be a dll file on Windows, it would be an exe file

Comment: please give me Zephir build command for exe i can edit it to make a dll file  on windows

Comment: There __isn't__ a zephir build command for a Windows environment; that's the whole point.... the best that can be done is [following this](https://github.com/phalcon/zephir/blob/master/WINDOWS.md)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I'm the one who implemented win32 support:

Despite the other comments, `zephir build` is supported but
`zephir install` is indeed not supported!

(as described in https://github.com/phalcon/zephir/blob/master/WINDOWS.md)

It also mentions that you just have to copy the built `.dll`
to your PHP-directory.
(And of course enable it by adding it to the php.ini)

It also seems that you are using an incompatible XDebug Version.
(which was built against a TS version of PHP, but you are using a NTS)

The error message `Installation is not implemented for windows yet! Aborting!` has nothing to say, it has been compiled at that point.

(zephir build is basically a "generate" -> "compile" -> "install" where only the last step fails - which is irrelevant, but still prints that message)

TLDR: Check if a dll has been created, copy & install it

Comment: sir i done this by NTS and TS version both the dll formed not worked with wamp and on cli it show message that "CLI has stopped working"

Comment: So you got a resulting DLL? If so that sounds like code is not properly generating - try to test with a small code base first.

Comment: sir i'm trying this code in extension:
  
`namespace Utils;

class Greeting
{

    public static function say()
    {
        echo "hello world!";
    }

}` and this is from _zephir Extension Skeleton_[http://zephir-lang.com/tutorial.html#extension-skeleton](http://zephir-lang.com/tutorial.html#extension-skeleton)