# Zephir installation on Windows OS

Tags: php, windows, xampp, zephir

I'm trying to start with [Zephir](https://docs.zephir-lang.com/0.10/en/installation) on Windows 10 OS, PHP Version 7.3.0.

I've to figure out the installation guide. I guess, I don't need [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) according to [Download and Install GCC Compiler in C for Windows PC](https://www.guru99.com/c-gcc-install.html), because `Visual C++ 2005 compiler` is already installed.

I've downloaded and installed Setup `re2c-0.9.4.exe` [Re2C for Windows](https://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/re2c.htm) instead [Re2C](https://re2c.org/).

In `C:\xampp\htdocs\user\test` I have `test.php`:

```
 <?PHP 
 require 'calc.zep';
 $m = new MyClass();
 $m->hello();
 ?>
```

Also, I've added [Zephir Syntax Highlight](https://%20https://github.com/zephir-lang/zephir-sublime) package to `Sublime Text 3 IDE` and created second document `calc.zep` with:

```
class MyClass
{
    public function hello()
    {
        echo "hello!";
    }
}
```

Then install [Zephir parser](https://github.com/zephir-lang/php-zephir-parser), locating [php_zephir_parser.dll](https://github.com/zephir-lang/php-zephir-parser/releases/tag/v1.5.1) version `zephir_parser-php-7.3-nts-windows2019-vc15-x64.zip` to `C:\xampp\php\ext`. Next, I've edited `C:\xampp\php\php.ini` file by adding these lines:

```
[Zephir Parser]
extension=php_zephir_parser.dll
```

to `Dynamic Extensions`,  but with `[Zephir Parser]` part of lines, xampp does not load localhost. So I've added it like this `;extension=php_zephir_parser` at the end of the extensions list, hope this is the correct way of edit for `php.ini` with extension adding:

```
    ...
    ;extension=pdo_sqlite
    ;extension=pgsql
    ;extension=shmop 
    ;extension=php_zephir_parser
```

According to [install Zephir Git Way](https://docs.zephir-lang.com/0.10/en/installation#git-way):

`git clone https://github.com/zephir-lang/zephir` to `C:\xampp\htdocs\user\test`, then `cd zephir` to `C:\xampp\htdocs\user\test\zephir` and `./install -c` which is

> not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program
> or batch file.

then `composer install`, and with `zephir help` or `zephir generate` I get this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Config' (T_STRING), expecting
> function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\user\test\zephir\Library\Logger\Formatter\CompilerFormatter.php
> on line 33

`composer -V` shows `Composer version 2.3.9`

`test.php` result is the same as without `php_zephir_parser.dll`:

> class MyClass { public function hello() { echo "hello!"; } }
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'MyClass' not found in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\user\test\test.php:5 Stack
> trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\user\test\test.php on line 5

Maybe I have to update PHP Version 7.3.0. to PHP Version 7.4.0.

Do I have to follow another guide [Zephir Installation/Usage Guide (Windows)](https://github.com/zephir-lang/zephir/blob/development/WINDOWS.md) or [PHP: A case for Zephir](https://medium.com/sean3z/php-a-case-for-zephir-1d9df68f8aa4) or I've missed or done something incorrectly with guidelines for installing the `Zephir` environment on Windows OS.

Any guide, advice, or example would be useful.

**edit:**

I've downloaded `php-8.1.12-Win32-vs16-x64` and added `php-8.1.12` folder to `C:\xampp` directory with keeping previous PHP Version 7.3.0 folder there.

In `php-8.1.12` folder I've created `php.ini` from the copy of `php.ini-development` and uncommented `extension_dir = "ext"`, `extension=curl`, `extension=ftp`, `extension=fileinfo`, `extension=openssl`, `extension=pdo_mysql` and `extension=pdo_sqlite`.

In `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp-config` file I've added  `PHP 8.1.12 Set-up ScriptAlias /php-8.1.12/ "C:/xampp/php-8.1.12/"` and `<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/user/test">`, according this [example httpd-xampp.conf](https://%20https://gist.github.com/Tynael/e69c0254c1ea3fc56420fe8441bb0764)

`<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/user/test">` shows `PHP Version 8.1.12` with  `phpinfo();` and CLI `php --version` inside `test` folder and keeps older PHP versions separately for other projects.

The result with `zephir help` command is successful: **Zephir 0.16.3** is installed, but `zephir generate` requires a parser:

> [ERROR]   The Zephir Parser extension is not loaded.   Note: Zephir
> no longer distributed with
> internal parser.   To install latest stable Zephir Parser please refer to:
> https://github.com/zephir-lang/php-zephir-parser

Then I've added `zephir_parser-php-8.1-nts-windows2019-vs16-x64.zip` `php_zephir_parser.dll` to `C:\xampp\php-8.1.12\ext`, then added `;extension=php_zephir_parser.dll` to `C:\xampp\php-8.1.12\php.ini`.

If I uncomment with removing semicolons `;` from `extension=php_zephir_parser.dll` I get the error:

> Server error! The server encountered an internal error and was unable
> to complete your request. Error message: malformed header from script
> 'php-cgi.exe': Bad header: 
>  Error 500 localhost Apache/2.4.37
> (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.1a PHP/7.3.0

With the restart of localhost I've changed  `extension=php_zephir_parser` to `extension=zephir_parser` and also have tried `extension=php_zephir_parser.dll`, in all cases `zephir build` command:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\user\test\zephir PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to
> load dynamic library 'zephir_parser' (tried: ext\zephir_parser (The
> specified module could not be found), ext\php_zephir_parser.dll (The
> specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'zephir_parser'
> (tried: ext\zephir_parser (The specified module could not be found),
> ext\php_zephir_parser.dll (The specified module could not be found))
> in Unknown on line 0
>
> [ERROR]   The Zephir Parser extension is not
> loaded.   Note: Zephir no longer distributed with internal parser.   To install latest stable Zephir Parser
> please refer to:
> https://github.com/zephir-lang/php-zephir-parser The system cannot find the path specified.  Preparing for PHP compilation... The
> system cannot find the path specified.  [ERROR]
> file_get_contents(ext\configure.js): Failed to open stream: No such
> file or directory

and `php --ini` from `C:\Users\User>`:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
> 'zephir_parser' (tried: ext\zephir_parser (The specified module could
> not be found), ext\php_zephir_parser.dll (The specified module could
> not be found)) in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'zephir_parser'
> (tried: ext\zephir_parser (The specified module could not be found),
> ext\php_zephir_parser.dll (The specified module could not be found))
> in Unknown on line 0
>
> Configuration File (php.ini) Path: Loaded Configuration File:
> C:\xampp\php-8.1.12\php.ini Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
> Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)

The answer on [error zephir_parser extension not loaded windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48268170/error-zephir-parser-extension-not-loaded-windows) says that's the using of extension via a web server, requires adding `extension=zephir_parser` to both the CLI and the `apache/fpm php.ini` files, but I can't find this directory in `C:\xampp\apache`.

According [Zephir Installation/Usage Guide (Windows)](https://github.com/zephir-lang/zephir/blob/development/WINDOWS.md) I've downloaded [php-debug-pack-8.1.12-Win32-vs16-x64.zip](https://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/) and [deps-7.1-vc14-x64.7z](https://windows.php.net/downloads/php-sdk/archives/). But then I installed it according to [Get Started with PHP SDK](https://www.contentstack.com/docs/developers/php/get-started-with-php-sdk/) with `composer require contentstack/contentstack` command to `C:\xampp\htdocs\user\test`

Comment: You seem to have jumped around between lots of different guides. Sometimes there's more than one way to do something, but that doesn't mean you can start with method 1, then switch to method 2 half-way through. Pick one, and stick to it, trying to figure out specific steps you get stuck on.

Comment: One thing you've definitely done, though, is downloaded the wrong DLL: the "php-8.1" refers to the version of PHP it will work with, but you say you're using PHP 7.3. (The fact that you're using [a PHP version which reached end of life last year](https://www.php.net/eol.php) may not be helping, if the guides you're following were written more recently.)

Comment: @IMSoP Hello, I've edited the question with all steps and points where I've stuck, which possibly is adding an extension to php.ini and ./install -c command not recognized. And Parse error with zephir help. I've changed the version with PHP 7.3 to zephir_parser-php-7.3-nts-windows2019-vc15-x64.zip